# Marker variable is undefined after get in Axios, VUE JS + LEAFLET + Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, leaflet, axios

The Axios response.data is okay. But when I use the markers variable in rendering the markers is undefined. I am a newbie and badly need your help for our project.

I am trying to render the markers from the link described in the code, but some I placed the axios request in the created, and in the mounted is the rendering of the leaflet map.

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YogSs.jpg)

```js
<script>
/** Script Vue JS **/
new Vue({
  el: '#view-map',
  data: {
    map,
    map_link:'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    markerOption: {
      clickable: true,
      draggable: false
    },
    mapOptions: {
      center: [7.3087, 125.6841],
      zoom:8  
    },
    markers:[], //[{"image":"GMS-4-0112018-467_1527086274.jpg","derivation_code":"GMS-4-0112018-467","sample_description":"test 1 test is a test that test will be tested in test","latitude":"6.428152","longitude":"125.317857"},{"image":"GMS-1-0112018-963_1527134301.jpg","derivation_code":"GMS-1-0112018-963","sample_description":"nalaya lang","latitude":"7.311647","longitude":"125.636461"}],
    selectedSample: [],
  },
  methods: {
    getMarkers: function (){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/marker').then(response => {
                    this.markers = response.data;
            }).catch(error =>( console.log(error) ));
    },
    renderMarker: function(){
      for ( i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
        console.log(this.markers[i]);
        var marker = new L.Marker([this.markers[i].latitude, this.markers[i].longitude], this.markerOption);
        marker.addTo(this.map);
        marker.bindPopup(`
            <h6 class="display-6">${this.markers[i].derivation_code}</h6>
            <img src="storage/images/${this.markers[i].image}" style="height:100%;width:100%">
        `);
      }
    },
    markerClicked: function(mrkr_data){
      this.selectedSample = mrkr_data.derivation_code;
      console.log(this.selectedSample);
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.getMarkers();
  },
  mounted: function(){
        this.map = new L.map('map', this.mapOptions);
        this.map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer(this.map_link));
        console.log(this.markers);
        this.renderMarker();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: done sir. I already updated my question

Comment: I think this is gonna be a good ol' race condition. Try putting a `console.log()` inside the response handler for `getMarkers()`, and see if that runs before or after `renderMarker()`. What is the value for `this.markers` inside ` renderMarker()`?

Comment: @IvanSanchez . the value of the renderMarker() is blank. But in the response of axios I tried to log it in the console the value is okay as expected, but outside of the axios declaration the even in the getMarkers function the markers variable is blank.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. I treated the fetching of data in Axios get property as a Synchronous but it is an Asynchronous. Base in my previous code, I accessed the data when it is not updated so the value is blank.

```js
/** Script Vue JS **/
new Vue({
  el: '#view-map',
  data: {
    map,
    map_link:'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    markerOption: {
      clickable: true,
      draggable: false
    },
    mapOptions: {
      center: [7.3087, 125.6841],
      zoom:8  
    },
    markers:[], //[{"image":"GMS-4-0112018-467_1527086274.jpg","derivation_code":"GMS-4-0112018-467","sample_description":"test 1 test is a test that test will be tested in test","latitude":"6.428152","longitude":"125.317857"},{"image":"GMS-1-0112018-963_1527134301.jpg","derivation_code":"GMS-1-0112018-963","sample_description":"nalaya lang","latitude":"7.311647","longitude":"125.636461"}],
    selectedSample: [],
  },
  created: function(){
     this.getMarkers();
  },
  mounted: function(){
        this.map = new L.map('map', this.mapOptions);
        this.map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer(this.map_link));
  }, 
  watch: {
    markers: function(){
        this.renderMarker();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMarkers: function (){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/marker').then(response => {
                    this.markers = response.data;
                    console.log(this.markers);
            }).catch(error =>( console.log(error) ));

        console.log(this.markers);
    },
    renderMarker: function(){
      for ( i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
        console.log(this.markers[i]);
        var marker = new L.Marker([this.markers[i].latitude, this.markers[i].longitude], this.markerOption);
        marker.addTo(this.map);
        marker.bindPopup(`
            <h6 class="display-6">${this.markers[i].derivation_code}</h6>
            <img src="storage/images/${this.markers[i].image}" style="height:100%;width:100%">
        `);
      }
    },
    markerClicked: function(mrkr_data){
      this.selectedSample = mrkr_data.derivation_code;
      console.log(this.selectedSample);
    }
  },
});
```